# How to fetch mails in Android using IMAP/POP3 protocols

Tags: java, android, email, imap, mail-server

I want to develop an Android application similar to [Typeapp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.trtf.blue&hl=en) . I want to know the algorithm behind it. Basically it would be a customised inbox with all IMPS/POP3 emails in a one application. If we have to configure this in java/Android to connect with IMAP server how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[K-9](https://k9mail.github.io/) is an open-sourced email-client, if the [license](https://github.com/k9mail/k-9#license) fits your project's requirements, then you can start from that code, and build on top of it:
See: https://k9mail.github.io/